# Celery for two backends (django, tornado)

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, tornado

everybody. 
I am working on online game where portal and admin panel is based on Django, while game and real-time services (feeds, chat) are based on Tornado non-blocking I\O.

For real-time transport we utilized SockJS-tornado and SockJS client.

I have a question regarding feeds module. Now we have the following architecture:

1. Feeds are generated on django side
2. Django publishes a task with parameters using celery.execute.send_task method
3. celery worker from tornado side consumes it and stores feeds for each subscriber in mongodb
4. tornado should also notify each **online subscriber** with fresh feed in real-time (the problem here that celery worker has different (isolated) environment)

However, there is a problem with 4th aforementioned point. Since celery and tornado has isolated environment, I have no access to **feed** handler. Is there a way to have access to an instance from another environment in celery environment by utilizing memcache; or may be celery somehow can share environment with application ?!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't get the `3. tornado consumes it` part, wouldn't that be `3. Celery consumes it`? As to your question, you could achieve 4. by having the Tornado server listen to the Broker on a dedicated Queue. Or it might be easier to simply have the Celery worker ping the Tornado server on a dedicated API once he's done with processing.

Comment: Thank you, I've corrected 3rd point.

Comment: Thank you! The first point is clear, but I am trying to find a solution with celery. The second point is a bit hard coding. In it's case, the question arises: "Why should I use celery than ?!". Is there a way to start celery in application environment where tornado server is starting, not as a separate worker ?! Or I have no other ways, as to use pika and built my own consumer ?! Or I should leave my attempts with celery and try zeromq ?!

Comment: The guys from [flower](https://github.com/mher/flower) are connecting to the broker from Tornado using Celery, so running a Celery Consumer should be feasible. I don't know much about Tornado, but it seems the main issue would be to have the worker run properly from the Tornado event loop. This solution seems cleaner. My point about the alternative, calling a dedicated API, was not very clear: I meant calling Tornado via HTTP from Celery, as explained [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/remote-tasks.html), which is interesting because it might require almost no extra work.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will use celery from Http:)

Comment: Finally solved. Later I will edit the question with constructive answer.